# boolean variable with conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I want to declare a boolean variable with the identifier condition5 and assign it a value based on the following instructions:

> The result of a boolean expression involving the boolean variables a and b that models the logical implication ( -> ) operator.
>
> The expected behavior is:
>
> - if both a and b are true, a -> b (i.e., a implies b) is true
> - if a is true and b is false, a -> b (i.e., a implies b) is false
> - if a is false, a -> b (i.e., a implies b) is true regardless of the value of b

And this my code:

```
boolean condition5 = false;
   if(a == true && b == true)
   {
       condition4 = true;
   }
   if(a == true && b == false)
   {
       condition4 = false;
   }
   if(a == false && b == false || b == true)
   {
       condition4 =  true;
   }
```

Comment: Is this your school assignment?

Comment: There is something wrong with my code as when i run the test file it gives me error. saying expression should evaluate true for a = true and b =true

Comment: yes i am not looking for someone to do me the assignment, i am looking for someone who can help me tell me where am i wrong

Comment: `condition4` should be `condition5`. So you're looking for someone to fix your typos? ;)

Comment: oh yeah, didnt see that. I fixed it now and the code is running fine like this. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help you. You can accept the answer below so the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
       boolean condition5 = false;
       if(a)
       {
           condition5 = b;
       }
       else
       {
       condition5 = true
       }
```

Try the above code. I just changed the variable name as suggested by **frhd**, and reduce the code length.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: `condition4` should be `condition5`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct answer. Read the comments below the question and report back.

Comment: Seen now (not in review queue, comment was masked), try to add some context when answering with a comment (even on typo answers) to ease the review and avoid this :)